# When trying to navigate displays error "cant find variable: navigation" in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, touchableopacity

I am trying to navigate to another page using `react-navigation` but it keeps displaying the same error, here is my code how I call it:

```
<TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.toggleModal}
        ></TouchableOpacity>

toggleModal = (item) => {
    navigation.navigate('TestHead');
};
```

And, I do have both classes in StackNavigator so I have no clue why is it showing this error!

**EDIT**

Here is how I export the navigator:

```
    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    Detail: SignIn,
    MultiSel: MultiSelectExample,
    TestHead : TestHeader
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Use `this.props.navigation.navigate('TestHead') `.

Comment: Can you please include more details about this issue? It is hard to reason about a really small piece of code that is put out of any context. You likely forgot about wrapping component with HOC, but it is hard to tell since you provided so little information.

Comment: @KishanBharda I have tried it like that as well but it throws another error.

Comment: @KacperWiszczuk I posted the code where I export the navigator, there is absolutely nothing else relevant to this.

Comment: Ofc there is. Most of the things you used aren't declared in the example, so there is no way to help you.

Comment: @KacperWiszczuk I have posted everything I am using. What are you thinking of that I am not posting here?

Comment: You could post the whole file with the component that is using navigate function. You could share with us the versions of the libraries that you are using.